# Check for duplicate entry from text file

Tags: c, file, duplicates, printf

I'm creating a simple program, I want to add some entry item into my records. If the item is found on the record, display the error message. Otherwise, print to the new line into the text file.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.txt","r+");

printf("Enter your name:");
scanf("%s",&result);

while(fscanf(fp,"%s",searchName) == 1)
{
 if(strmp(searchName,result))
 //Do something
}
```

How to display errror message if found in the record and print to new line if doesn't exist in the record ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) not `strmp` as per your post.

you can use like

```
if(strcmp(searchName,result) == 0){
    printf("error : Already in record\n");
    break;
 }
 else
 //code to add record
```